# horizontal tab escape not working in string.Format

Tags: c#, winforms

```
string1 = "hello";
string2 = "world";
```

Why is it that

```
string.Format("{0}\t{1}",string1,string2);
```

does not register the horizontal tab? It displays as `helloworld` instead of `hello    world`.

Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Displays *where*?

Comment: Click the loupe in the debugger and you'll see that it works.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine with me? Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}", string1, string2)); prints hello         world

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen on a label

Comment: seems label doesn't support tab..well too bad for me..guess i have to go with padding.